# Responsiveness of Checkbox with an input group’s addon

Tags: html, angular

This is the part of the HTML file of my Angular project, where I am using a checkbox with an input groups addon

```
<td
   style="width: auto; word-wrap: normal"
   class="text-wrap"
   >
   <fieldset>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
         <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div
               class="input-group-text"
               style="height: 30px"
               >
               <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="checkbox-addon1"
                  class="form-check-input"
                  />
            </div>
         </div>
         <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Compare data"
            style="height: 30px; width: 80px"
            />
      </div>
   </fieldset>
</td>
```

When seeing this on desktop, it is showing in a correct way -

[image]

But when the same thing I am seeing in  mobile view, I see like this

[image]

**In mobile view, checkbox and text are not coming in the same line. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?**

**Edit 1:**

I have defined the heading of this table column as

```
<th style="width: 9em" scope="col">Compare data</th>
```

**Edit 2:**

Based on what @HAPPY SINGH answered,
I tried using the below part of code, in my scss file

```
.input-group {
  white-space: nowrap;
  .form-control {
    width: 50px !important;
    padding-left: 0%;
    padding-right: 0%;
  }
}
```

But as soon as I change from `width: 40px`, the mobile view breaks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
Use this few style CSS and remove inline CSS added in external CSS.

**Mobile view media query:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .input-group {
       white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .form-control {
       width: 40px;
    }   
}
```

Comment: do I need to make any change in the HTML file, or just by including the above code in .scss file will work ?

Comment: @ESCoder, Just modification on the stylesheet.
In .scss just add the code.  
.input-group { white-space: nowrap; .form-control { width: 40px !important; } }

Comment: yes, this worked :D Checkbox and input text is coming in the same line, but the text part is coming in a very small width, so the complete data is not visible

Comment: I tried increasing the width in your part of the code, but then the checkbox and input text box come in a separate line. Is there any way I can increase the width of input text ?

Comment: Yeah, you just need to reduce padding-left and padding-right and also increase width:50px !important. I think I would be visible properly.

Comment: I tried with what you said, and added my code in the question above. After changing from 40 -> 50, the mobile view breaks again. Is there any issue in the code ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3" style="white-space: nowrap">
```

or

```
<div class="input-group mb-3" style="display:flex">
```

to disallow wrapping.

On the other hand, it is likely that `.input-group` already does this. Your elements are contained in a table column, and table will always display all of its columns, even when there is not enough screen space available, which is likely why the layout breaks. Rather than using tables for layout, prefer a flexbox approach instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but even after using your part of code, I get the same mobile view as shown above in the question

Comment: try this: <div class="input-group mb-3" style="display: flex;">

Comment: `display:flex` should work. @Juan should write that up as an answer, instead.

Comment: Ok @AlexandervanOostenrijk, I write down as answer.thxs!

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk I tried with what Juan suggested but got the same issue. Is it because of the way I have defined my column heading?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the table column all this is in. Try not using tables for layout, and a flexbox approach instead.

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk thanks I will try out the flexbox approach as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3" style="display: flex;">
```

Comment: I tried with this also, but again getting the same mobile view issue, as shown above in the question. Is it because of the way I have defined my column heading?